# Keychain access code leaking

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

Here is the leak:
[image]

And here is my code:

```
+(NSString *)getSecureValueForKey:(NSString *)key {

    // Retrieve a value from the keychain
    NSDictionary *result;
    NSArray *keys = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kSecClass, kSecAttrAccount, kSecReturnAttributes, nil] autorelease];
    NSArray *objects = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kSecClassGenericPassword, key, kCFBooleanTrue, nil] autorelease];
    NSDictionary *query = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: objects forKeys: keys];

    // Check if the value was found
    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef) query, (CFTypeRef *) &result);
    [query release];
    if (status != noErr) {
        // Value not found
        return nil;
    } else {
        // Value was found so return it
        NSString *value = (NSString *) [result objectForKey: (NSString *) kSecAttrGeneric];
        return value;
        [result release];
    }
}

+(BOOL)storeSecureValue:(NSString *)value forKey:(NSString *)key {
    // Get the existing value for the key
    NSString *existingValue = [self getSecureValueForKey:key];

    // Check if a value already exists for this key
    OSStatus status;
    if (existingValue) {
        // Value already exists, so update it
        NSArray *keys = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kSecClass, kSecAttrAccount, nil] autorelease];
        NSArray *objects = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kSecClassGenericPassword, key, nil] autorelease];
        NSDictionary *query = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: objects forKeys: keys] autorelease];
        status = SecItemUpdate((CFDictionaryRef) query, (CFDictionaryRef) [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey: (NSString *) kSecAttrGeneric]);
    } else {
        // Value does not exist, so add it
        NSArray *keys = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kSecClass, kSecAttrAccount, kSecAttrGeneric, nil] autorelease];
        NSArray *objects = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kSecClassGenericPassword, key, value, nil] autorelease];
        NSDictionary *query = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: objects forKeys: keys] autorelease];
        status = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef) query, NULL);
    }

    // Check if the value was stored
    if (status != noErr) {
        // Value was not stored
        return false;
    } else {
        // Value was stored
        return true;
    }
}
```

Can you help me fix it? The leak is everytime I access or store data in the keychain.
I haven't programmed without ARC for a lot of time, and I just can't track this leak down!

Thank you!

Comment: Do `[result release];` before `return value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release `keys` and `objects` after creating `query`, release `result` *before* returning `value`, actually release new objects created during your store secure value method.

At this point, your options are, learn how memory management actually works, or just turn on ARC and let it handle most of that for you.

Comment: `keys` and `objects` are autoreleased. I would rather release them manually, but still, they don't leak.